# Async methond within OnCreate Event (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a Async Method, which checks the "Login Status" of the user. it returns true or false, then based upon the result I open the desired activity. My problem is Async method is not respecting the "await" keyword and it continues the process to next event (OnResume). is there anyway i can have onCreate wait for Async method to complete before calling OnResume event?

```
         protected  override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


            var s = await UserLoginStatusAsync(); //<-- From here it jumps to OnResume event

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
}
        protected  override async void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            var _network = this.isNetworkAvailable();

            bool userStatus = await UserLoginStatusAsync(); //<-- Jumps here 
            var a = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wait method of the Task. Such as

```
Task result = UserLoginStatusAsync();
result.Wait();
```

You can also use the Thread.sleep(1000) to make the main thread sleep for a while. But this will reduce the function of the application because we don't know how long time the async method need and if the time if more than 5 seconds will cause the ANR.